# Function not found in an R package?

Tags: r, function, package

I have been working with the `minfi` R package. All the functions used to work fine in it, when I worked with another computer. I installed `minfi` 2 days back in my own laptop. Most of the functions work fine, but when i use a command which has a function `preprocessSWAN()`, I get the error

```
Error: could not find function ¨proprocessSWAN¨
```

I get this error everytime I work with this function only, in the midway of running my analysis.

I had also tried reinstalling `minfi` to see if something had gone wrong during the installation. But even after reinstalling, I find the same problem. This function works fine on my windows and also the other computer.

Can anyone tell me why am i having this problem in my ubuntu ? And what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Is it not a typo? It says "proprocess" the second time in your question. If not try `getFromNamespace("preprocessSWAN", "minfi")`. It could hardly have been removed from the package, but with such a specific name it is not likely to be overlaid by another method either.

Comment: @Backlin: It is surely not a typo.. I mistakely typed ¨pro¨ here but i checked and did it right several times in R. I also tried getFromNamespace("preprocessSWAN", "minfi") , but it says , Error in get(x, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'preprocessSWAN' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggestion checking that you have the same version on each machine. Look at the [NEWS](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/news/minfi/NEWS) for the package, suggests that `preprocessSWAN()` is fairly new. So, look at:

```
library(minfi)
packageVersion("minfi")
```

on each machine you own. I realise that you updated your package, but your really need to check that all your bioconductor packages are up to date. So, try something like:

```
url='http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R'
source(url)
update.packages(repos=biocinstallRepos())
```

Also, are you running the same version of R? Type `version` on both machines. To get the same bioconductor version you will (I think) need the same version of R. So you may need to upgrade R.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @csgillespie. I am working on upgrading R. And sorry about posting it as an answer.